# Can a lower-semi continuous function be convex?

Tags: continuity, convex-optimization

In an image processing paper I was reading about a class of functions:

$\Gamma(\mathbb{R}^N)$ is the class of proper, convex, lower semi-continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}^N \rightarrow \left] -\infty, +\infty \right]$.

Then I was drawing a function similar to this (but quadratic, without the tailes).

[image: sup]

Then I noticed that this function cannot be convex. Then I questioned whether even semi-continuous function can be convex?

---

Can anyone say something about this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For example, the following is a convex l.s.c. function from $\mathbb R$ to $]-\infty, \infty]$:
$$ f(x) = \cases{0 & if $|x| \le 1$ \cr
                 +\infty & otherwise}
$$

Comment: More examples: continuous convex functions.